# Magento 2 - How to replace a char on item title

Tags: magento2, template, page-title

I have succesfully used this trick to replace dash char "-" with "br" on CATEGORY VIEW:

```
<?php echo str_replace(' - ', '<br />', $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name')); ?>
```

result --> https://dev.push96.com/uomo.html

But now how can I use the same trick on the PRODUCT PAGE title?
--> https://dev.push96.com/uomo/tommy-jeans-uomo-t-shirt-in-puro-cotone-giallo-con-logo-dm0dm05125094.html

I need the same replace "-" with line break but I can't find where to put the code.

Comment: use "Template hints", you will know the location of file where product title is located. Then edit title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your code here:

> /app/code/Custom/module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" type="Custom\Module\Block\Html\Title" />
</config>
```

> /app/code/Custom/Module/Block/Html/Title.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Html page title block
 *
 * @method $this setTitleId($titleId)
 * @method $this setTitleClass($titleClass)
 * @method string getTitleId()
 * @method string getTitleClass()
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Title extends Template
{
    /**
     * Own page title to display on the page
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $pageTitle;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->registry = $registry;    
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {      
        if($this->registry->registry('current_product')) {
            return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        }
        return false;        
    }
}
```

Now you can update your prodcut name here

> /app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml

```
$product = $block->getCurrentProduct();
```

And then apply your logic there.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: Your reply opened my mind and I got an illlumination :) I just overrided the file "/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/mytemplate/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml" and it works!

Comment: Welcome :). And +1 for accepting as answer